# How to remove/uninstall fuerte completely?

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to install ros groovy and I want to remove everything related to ros fuerte what so ever. I don't want to have any kind of problems due to conflicts between the new groovy and the old version of ros that I'm currently using and for that, I want a complete removal. Will the following do the job?

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*
```

Or I should delete some certain files/directories manually?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48627/how-to-remove/uninstall-fuerte-completely?/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will not have any problems when you install Fuerte and Groovy in parallel. If you really want to get rid of Fuerte, your apt-get command should do the job.

But note that Groovy is not released yet. As far as I know, it even didn't reach beta yet. I would expect a lot of problems and wait with the update.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on 2012-11-20**:
Indeed! I'm having lot's of problem with it :/